# MySQL apply filter on joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, filter

Let's assume we have a database with physical cuboids, defined as objects. Each object has a length, width and height. as shown in the example below.

```
CREATE TABLE dimensions(
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    value int
);

CREATE TABLE object(
    id int,
    dimension VARCHAR(100),
    dimension_value_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (dimension_value_id) REFERENCES dimensions(id)
);

INSERT INTO dimensions VALUES(0, 100);
INSERT INTO dimensions VALUES(1, 200);
INSERT INTO dimensions VALUES(2, 300);
INSERT INTO dimensions VALUES(3, 400);

INSERT INTO object VALUES(0, "length", 1);
INSERT INTO object VALUES(0, "width", 3);
INSERT INTO object VALUES(0, "height", 2);

INSERT INTO object VALUES(1, "length", 1);
INSERT INTO object VALUES(1, "width", 1);
INSERT INTO object VALUES(1, "height", 2);
```

My goal is to filter the objects for the ones that have a smaller dimension than are smaller 251x251x350, in the example this would be object with the id 1.

When joining the tables I get the records:

```
SELECT * FROM object o
JOIN dimensions d ON o.dimension_value_id = d.id
```

but how can now a filter be applied. I came across a solution with exists/not exists. But in this case this would not work, because I would need to have an exclusive not exists.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: These could be cuboids, but they aren't squares ?!?!? Incidentally, the number in parentheses after an INT declaration is almost entirely meaningless - which is just as well in this instance, as the allowable number described would be larger than the number of atoms in the universe.

Comment: Smaller compared to what? All dimensions or the volume?

Comment: compared to all dimensions. 
Also the orientation should be ignored, meaning I want to rotate if needed to achieve the smaller condition, independent of the original orientation.

Comment: Does this mean that the greater of the 3 dimensions of the object must be less than the smaller of of the 3: 251x251x350 so 251 so the object can be rotated?

Comment: Let's say we have an object of size 250x250x300 and want to check if we can fit it into a box of size 251x251x350. So we are free to rotate however we wan't. Means I also want to fit it if the given box is 251x350x251 or 350x251x251. Do you get my intention?

Comment: Oh, the issues one has with EAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must compare the smaller of the 3 dimensions with the smaller of the 3 values, the greatest dimension with the greatest of the 3 values and the middle one with the middle  of the 3 values:

```
select o.id 
from object o inner join dimensions d 
on o.dimension_value_id = d.id
group by o.id 
having 
  min(d.value) < least(251, 251, 350) 
  and 
  max(d.value) < greatest(251, 251, 350)
  and
  max(case when o.dimension = 'length' then d.value end) + 
  max(case when o.dimension = 'width' then d.value end) +
  max(case when o.dimension = 'height' then d.value end) -
  (min(d.value) + max(d.value)) < 
  (251 + 251 + 350) - (least(251, 251, 350) + greatest(251, 251, 350))
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mzFngFn8K3QSmRKQ7L6Q6k/1).
A simplified version for passing parameters like `251, 251, 350`:

```
select o.id 
from object o inner join dimensions d 
on o.dimension_value_id = d.id
cross join (select 251 as col1, 251 as col2, 350 as col3) t
group by o.id 
having 
  min(d.value) < least(max(t.col1), max(t.col2), max(t.col3)) 
  and 
  max(d.value) < greatest(max(t.col1), max(t.col2), max(t.col3))
  and
  max(case when o.dimension = 'length' then d.value end) + 
  max(case when o.dimension = 'width' then d.value end) +
  max(case when o.dimension = 'height' then d.value end) -
  (min(d.value) + max(d.value)) < 
  (max(t.col1) + max(t.col2) + max(t.col3)) - (
    least(max(t.col1), max(t.col2), max(t.col3)) + 
    greatest(max(t.col1), max(t.col2), max(t.col3))
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mzFngFn8K3QSmRKQ7L6Q6k/4).

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation.  This would look like:

```
SELECT o.id 
FROM object o JOIN
     dimensions d 
     ON o.dimension_value_id = d.id
GROUP BY o.id 
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN o.dimension = 'length' THEN d.value END)) < 350 AND
       MAX(CASE WHEN o.dimension = 'width' THEN s.value END)) < 350 AND
       MAX(CASE WHEN o.dimension = 'height' THEN d.value END)) < 350;
```